# Need help in my VueJS + VueX + Firebase project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, vuex

I am trying to show the current `userName` and `title` which was already created by signin and now stored in [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) database.

But I don't know how to handle this, I can't find an error in the code by my self.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
<div id="dashboard">
    <section>
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="profile">
                <h5>{{ userProfile.name }}</h5>
                <p>{{ userProfile.title }}</p>
                <div class="create-post">
                    <p>create a post</p>
                    <form @submit.prevent>
                        <textarea v-model.trim="post.content"></textarea>
                        <button @click="createPost" 
         class="button">post</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div>
                <p class="no-results">There are currently no posts</p>
            </div>
        </div>
       </section>
   </div>
 </template>

 <script>
    const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    import firebase from 'firebase'
    const db = firebase.firestore()

    export default {
     data() {
       return {
         post: {
            content: ''
         }
       }
     },
     computed: {
        ...mapState(['userProfile'])
     },
     methods: {
       createPost() {
         fb.postsCollection.add({
            createdOn: new Date(),
            content: this.post.content,
            userId: this.currentUser.uid,
            userName: this.userProfile.name,
            comments: 0,
            likes: 0
        }).then(ref => {
            this.post.content = ''
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Store.js

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Vuex from 'vuex'
  const fb = require('./firebaseConfig.js')

  Vue.use(Vuex)

  // handle page reload
  fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
    store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
   }
  })

  export const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
     currentUser: null,
     userProfile: {}
   },
   actions: {
    clearData ({ commit }) {
      commit('setCurrentUser', null)
      commit('setUserProfile', {})
    },
    fetchUserProfile ({
      commit,
      state
    }) {
    fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).get().then(res => {
      commit('setUserProfile', state.res.data())
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
      console.log(state)
    }
   },
   mutations: {
     setCurrentUser (state, val) {
       state.currentUser = val
    },
    setUserProfile (state, val) {
      state.userProfile = val
    }
   }
})
```

Error output:

[image]

userProfile output as Object:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the component code?

Comment: from which component?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, instead use the code-tag. Also you did not share your Dashboard.vue, where the error seems to originate from.

Comment: i am sorry that'S my first post

Comment: Did you console and see if the userProfile state has value?

Comment: userProfile is undefined

Comment: so I change in store.js in actions -> fetchUserProfile the line commit('setUserProfile', state.res.data()) after this userProfile is an Object

Comment: The component is trying to access properties of userProfile before that data has been retrieved from firebase.  Either init userProfile as an empty object, or try wrapping those parts of the template in a `v-if="userProfile"` (so the template won't try to read data until after it exists) to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: yes it worked thanks